# how to add new PHP page in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development

im a beginner in WordPress and i'm trying to modify a plugin and everything is going smoothly, yet whenever i create new PHP page and try require or anything it gives error and i can't access WP classes nor WP functions.
what is the best way to insert new php page to plugin?.

Comment: What do you mean "create new PHP page"? Where? How?

Comment: like im trying to create new php page in the plugin so i can manage to send requests and so from it without changing the main code, yet in that page i can't access wp functions.

Comment: That's not really how plugins work. I suggest taking a look at the plugin handbook to learn how they're built: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/ And if you need to modify an existing plugin you will need to consult its support resources for ways to do that. It's not going to be a matter of just dropping PHP files into existing plugin folders (these would be deleted if the plugin was updated anyway).

Comment: i changed the plugin name and so, my only concern is how to require wordpress functions, in functions.php i included my page but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to include the PHP file into the main plugin file, not the other way around.

Comment: i tried that yet it doesn't work still and whenever i try to access a class it give an error, can you please help me i just have to make it access WordPress functions and plugin classes.

Comment: There’s not enough information in your question about what exactly you’re trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a payment gateway and it sends the request and all yet for the response it gives back html resposne so i receive it in JS and send it again to another php page to be able to process data then sent approval for payment gateway but after the second request i can't access the classes to change the status or access wordpress functions like wp_send_json.

Comment: You never call a PHP file in your plugin directory in a browser directly. You call a virtual page in WordPress, and then execute your plugin code in that context.